# Which design pattern should I use for this?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a piece of logic that I need to execute either once or multiple times (in a loop) based on the type. Does a strategy pattern make sense here? In essence:

```
if (type == 1)
{
   ProcessReport("");
}
else if (type == 2)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < numUsers; i++)
   {
     ProcessReport(userId);
   }
}

public void ProcessReport(string id)
{
   if (id == "")
   {
     //Send full report
   }

   else
   {
     GetReportFragment();

     //Send report
   }
}
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken wouldn't this work better using the Repository Pattern..? just a thought at first glance..

Comment: Please note, design patterns are not the ANSWER to a problem, but they are SOLUTION to specific problems. So use it wisely. In your case i do not see a reason for the pattern.

Comment: The code snippet is too short for definite suggestions. When talking about design patterns, it is much more useful to try to explain your problems, workflows, behaviors, to give a wider picture of a problem. One `if/else` statement in your code does not imply that you should immediately change your design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually the Strategy pattern define a family of algorithms, encapsulate each one, and make them interchangeable. Strategy lets the algorithm vary independently from clients that use it.

I don't see any complex algorithms for which worth add another layer of abstraction

If you want to encapsulate the ProcessReport behavior I would create an interface that represent this behavior so that you can just call `IProcessReport.Process(userId)` in your loop

Answer (score 4):

Well, since you obviously use a "type code" to distinguish different behaviors, you could start by [replacing it with subclasses (polymorphism)](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-type-code-with-subclasses). That's usually the first thing to do when there is a type code based branching.

For simple problems, however, this might be an overkill. What's more objectionable with your code is:

- the use of **magic numbers** for your types: you should at least change them to enums to improve readability
- passing **empty parameters** (`""`) to indicate specific behavior: at least create a separate method for a "full report", if you don't have an ID to specify

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the semantics of the `type` variable, it might make sense to use polymorphism.

Given the current example it may be overhead (there are only two branches), but every time you see structures like `if() ... else if() ... else if() ...` or `switch() { case: ... }` you have to wonder: how many conditional branches will there be? Is it likely that there will appear new ones in the future?

Depending on the answers to these questions we may decide to do a [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html) refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be simplified to this:

```
if (type == 1)
    SendFullReport();
else if (type == 2)
    for (int i = 0; i < numUsers; i++)
        GetReportFragment(userId);
```

Of course, you'll have to implement the `SendFullReport()` and `GetReportFragment(string userId)` methods.

There's no point in using complex design patterns in this context.

Answer (score 0):

So, it's just an example or it is the actual size? I mean, if you have two types, the best pattern to use is to keep it simple :).

If you have several types, then you can have a strategy there, or a dictionary type-delegate/command with the code you want to execute.

Comment: This is just an example. The actual code is way too large to post here

Comment: Ok, so a dictionary of type-command will be enough. If the commands are too simple, you can just use delegates.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the strategy pattern is the right solution despite how simple the current function is. In general, I avoid 'if' statements and trying to atomize my code. Groo's observations on the code 'smells' are mine too. Polymorphism (strategy) may appear to be overkill, but I would rather a slightly more abstract solution than attempting to change the behaviour of a function based on a string parameter that is hopefully empty or a number.